# Using invoke command gives dot sourcing error

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command, dot-source

I'm trying to access a remote computer using `Invoke-Command` but I keep getting the following error:

> Cannot dot-source this command because it was defined in a different language mode. To invoke this command without importing its contents, omit the '.' operator.

I'm not dot sourcing it so I don't get why this error is showing up.
Here's my code:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ip  -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {bcdedit /v}
```

Assume that `$ip` and `$cred` store valid arguments

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to diagnose your problem. Where are you invoking this from? Please directly update your question with clarifications.

Comment: A quick google will give you the information you need: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-constrained-language-mode-and-the-dot-source-operator/